# Vim Case-Agnostic Regex

Tags: regex, vim

I've run into the following case a few times and I was wondering if there is a fast way to handle it in Vim.

I'll have a source file like the following:

```
#ifndef _FOO_H_
#define _FOO_H_

class Foo {
    Foo(int foo);
};
#endif
```

And I would like to convert it to the following:

```
#ifndef _BAR_H_
#define _BAR_H_

class Bar {
    Bar(int bar);
};
#endif
```

So, I want all foo -> bar, but to keep the capitalization of the original.  Right now, I've been doing this with 3 or 4 different regexes, but it seems there should be a better way.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=6) will do a case-preserving search/replace.

Copy the script to the plugin directory (`~/.vim/plugin`), then do

```
:set ic
:%s/foo/\=KeepCaseSameLen(submatch(0), 'bar')/g
```

Comment: You should update your version of keepcase. I've added a :SubstituteCase command to it that simplifies substitutions a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

Tim Pope's [Vim Abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) plugin can do this and a whole ton more. `:%Subvert/string/new string/g` will preserve case, capitalization, etc., and the plugin also supports word variants using a `{var1,var2}` syntax. Very useful.